# To schedule for automation which is best Maven or Jenkins?

Tags: selenium

I have list of Selenium Webdriver testcase written in Junit Test cases which runs, on demand. currently i am running that and manually sending the report for Pass/Fail count on weekend.

I need that it should run on each weekend and send out the report to me for pass/fail count. There are two tools i come across. Jenkins and maven. I am new to both.. which is best for requirement?

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is the correct option here

Maven is a build tool, where we know the build procedure and its dependencies
It can be used in your project to create the class file or jar files required

Jenkins is a Continuous Integration tool, which can be used to schedule and run tasks where you can execute your test cases , report the test result via email.. you can view it as server which executes your tests and provide you the results